# Google Cloud Platform - google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the google.cloud python libs to do a storage.buckets.get request. I'm using a Json file for my credentials and have assigned both the Owner role and Storage Admin role to my IAM account as outlined in other answers but I'm still getting this error

[IAM role permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVNkg.png)

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Coding Projects\Transcriber\Transcriber.py", line 129, in 
transcript = google_transcribe(audio_file_name)
File "D:\Coding Projects\Transcriber\Transcriber.py", line 81, in google_transcribe
upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)
File "D:\Coding Projects\Transcriber\Transcriber.py", line 51, in upload_blob
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage\client.py", line 407, in get_bucket
retry=retry,
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage\bucket.py", line 1007, in reload
retry=retry,
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage_helpers.py", line 225, in reload
retry=retry,
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage_http.py", line 78, in api_request
return call()
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 290, in retry_wrapped_func
on_error=on_error,
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 188, in retry_target
return target()
File "C:\Users\tomda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 483, in api_request
raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/callsaudiofiles?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: ******************.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: The error message is very clear. The service account in the error does not have permission. Note: Owner does not need Storage Admin. You have probably assigned the roles to the wrong account, or you are using the wrong account. Questions with only long error/stack traces is not very useful for others. Show your code, the roles assigned, where you are running this code, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley No, I've confirmed to be using the correct account. Privilege's are as seen in attached screenshot in the original post. Stack trace shows the full error and context which I would find useful.

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong. You have configured something incorrectly. `******************.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.`